# session.cookie_lifetime not working for Firefox?

Tags: php, zend-framework, firefox

In my **Zend Application**, I am trying to make our ***authenticated users be automatically logged out*** when ***they close their browser***.

For that I'd write following code:

`ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',  0);`

And its working fine on browsers like *Chrome, Safari, IE7 and IE8*, but ***in case of firefox, users still remain logged on when they close their browser.***

Does anyone know what is causing problem?

Thanks In advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A value of `0` indicates "session cookie" - i.e. one that the browser *should* destroy when the "session" is over and the browser is closed.

However:

- Different browsers have different interpretations of exactly what a "session" is - some will destroy these cookies when your close the tab, some when you close the window, some won't destroy the cookies until all instances of the browser have been closed - all tabs in all windows.
- Since cookies are stored and transmitted by the client, they are completely the responsibility of the client. You should not rely on cookies alone to control whether a user has a valid login because they are ridiculously easy to spoof, you should implement some kind of activity timeout as well.

Make sure you have actually ended your Firefox session when testing - close *all* open tabs and windows, and watch the process list to ensure there are no instances left. If you are still having a problem, you are probably looking at some kind of bug in Firefox (or maybe you've made some strange change in `about:config`) and you need to ask for Firefox-specific help - [SuperUser.com](http://www.superuser.com/) would be a better place for that. One thing you can be fairly sure of is that if it works everywhere else, it's not a problem with your PHP.